# "Could not execute query error" in Web Services with NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services, nhibernate

As the title says, I am getting this error:

> could not execute query
>   [ SELECT this_.Id as Id5_0_, this_.Username as Username5_0_, this_.PasswordHash as Password3_5_0_, this_.Salt as Salt5_0_, this_.Token as Token5_0_, this_.TokenStamp as TokenStamp5_0_, this_.Role as Role5_0_ FROM User this_ ]"
>   error when breakpointing.

I am trying to make a simple login with user in database where the user types in username and password hash. I have a user data which has Admin on every column to debug with.

Here's my code:

SQL Server database:

`User` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] 
(
    [Id]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Username]     NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [PasswordHash] CHAR (64)        NOT NULL,
    [Salt]         CHAR (64)        NOT NULL,
    [Role]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Token]        NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [TokenStamp]   DATETIME         NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Role] FOREIGN KEY ([Role]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([Id])
);
```

`Role` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role]  
(
    [Id]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Role] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

`WebService.cs`:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Services;
using NHibernate;
using Models;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://LambdAlarm.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class LambdAlarmWebService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public HttpStatusCode Login(string username, string passwordHash)
    {
        var factory = SessionFactory.Instance;
        var session = factory.OpenSession();
        var result = session.QueryOver<User>().List<User>();
        var user = new User();
        var login = result.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

        if (user.Username == login.Username)
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }

        return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
}
```

`User` model:

```
using System;

namespace Models
{
    public class User : EntityBase
    {
        public virtual string Username { get; set; }
        public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public virtual string Salt { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual string Token { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime TokenStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Role` model:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Role : EntityBase
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`EntityBase`: (class with one `Guid` property inherited by all models)

```
using System;

namespace Models
{
    public class EntityBase
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`UserMap`: (NHibernate mapping)

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Models;

namespace NHibernate.Mapping
{
    public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Table("User");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            LazyLoad();
            References(x => x.Role).Column("Role");
            Map(x => x.Username).Column("Username");
            Map(x => x.PasswordHash).Column("PasswordHash").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Salt).Column("Salt").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Token).Column("Token").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.TokenStamp).Column("TokenStamp");
        }
    }
}
```

`RoleMap`:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Models;

namespace NHibernate.Mapping
{
    public class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role>
    {
        public RoleMap()
        {
            Table("Role");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            LazyLoad();
            Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

`SessionFactory`:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using Models;
using NHibernate.Conventions;

namespace NHibernate
{
    public static class SessionFactory
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        public static ISessionFactory Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    _sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
                }

                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                            .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DatabaseConnectionString")))
                        .Mappings(m =>
                        {
                            m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomForeignKeyConvention>();
                            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EntityBase>();
                        })
                        .BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

`Conventions`:

```
using FluentNHibernate;
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions;

namespace NHibernate.Conventions
{
    public class CustomForeignKeyConvention : ForeignKeyConvention
    {
        protected override string GetKeyName(Member property, System.Type type)
        {
            if (property == null)
            {
                return type.Name;
            }

            return property.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

So that's pretty much it. If there is anyone who can help out, would be much appreciated...

Comment: Have you looked at all the inner exception? Most of the time this will contain useful explanation of what actually went wrong. The exception text you quoted is just NHibernate's way of providing additional context to the true error information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User is a reserved word in sql. You can rename your table or make nhibernate use `` around the table name. I guess that if you change

```
Table("User");
```

to

```
Table("`User`");
```

it will work.

Comment: I believe [using backticks](https://benl.wordpress.com/2006/04/21/nhibernate-tip-escaping-column-names) is the correct way - "NHibernate replaces backticks at runtime with the correct escaping sequence for your chosen database dialect"